# Laravel add seeder function to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, seed

i want to add a button "reset" in the backend which just runs all seeders if it is pressed to reset the data to the standard?
There must be a way to do this because I am probably not the only one that has this idea but unfortunatly i can't find anything online.

Thank you for responding in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call artisan commands directly from your code. For example the one below 
refresh all seeds and migrations.

which is same as `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

```
Route::get('/reset', function(){
    \Artisan::call('migrate:refresh',['--seed' => ' ']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run an artisan command from your controller:

```
Artisan::call('migrate:fresh'); // = php artisan migrate:fresh
Artisan::call('db:seed'); // = php artisan db:seed

// OR
Artisan::call('migrate:fresh', ['--seed' => true]);
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SomeModel::truncate();` to remove all existing data. After removing objects you could run `$this->call(someTableSeeder::class);` to seed the table again.

You can also call artisan commands in your PHP code (see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands) in this case you could use something like `Artisan::call('db:seed');`